# Why my state variable is undefined despite the fact that I have initiated it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have created this state variable `num` and initiated it with integer value 1. But despite being initialized with the value it shows that it is undefined.

Code:-

```
import React, { useState} from "react";
import { ArrowCircleLeftIcon, StarIcon, XCircleIcon, PlusIcon} from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import AnswerBox from "./Test/Test";

function Test() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    show: true,
    num:1,
    title: "",
    hide:false,
  });

  return (
    <div className="bg-white relative p-10 flex flex-row items-center align-middle shadow-2xl rounded-2xl">
      <div
        className={
          state.show
            ? "flex flex-col items-center align-middle"
            : "absolute scale-0 opacity-0 h-0 w-0"
        }
      >
        <h1 className="heading">Schedule Tests</h1>
        <select
          onChange={(e) => setState({ show: false, title: e.target.value })}
          className="h-12 text-xl p-2 border-black border-2"
        >
          <option>Select Class</option>
          <option>Demo class A</option>
          <option>Demo class B</option>
          <option>Demo class C</option>
          <option>Demo class D</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div
        className={
          state.show
            ? "absolute scale-0 opacity-0 h-0 w-0"
            : "flex flex-col items-center align-middle p-3"
        }
      >
        <div className={state.hide ? "absolute scale-0 h-0 w-0 opacity-0":"absolute transition-all duration-150 origin-bottom text-4xl left-[-7rem] h-auto top-[-1rem] z-50 opacity-[.93] bg-blue-600 text-white rounded-lg shadow p-8"}>
          <div className="flex flex-col">
            <div className="flex flex-row items-center m-auto">
              <StarIcon className="h-[5rem] w-[5rem] rounded-full mr-2 bg-blue-400 text-yellow-400 rotate-[-12deg] shadow-2xl shadow-blue-800" />
              <h1 className="text-[4rem]">Tips</h1>
              <XCircleIcon onClick={() => setState({...state,hide:true})} className="h-[4rem] w-[4rem] rounded-full text-red-400 hover:scale-110 hover:text-red-500 transition-all duration-200 origin-center cursor-pointer absolute right-0 top-0"/>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-row mb-6 mt-6">
              <StarIcon className="h-12 w-12 rounded-full bg-blue-400 mr-2" />
              How to put a Text Answer?
            </div>
            <div className="bg-blue-400 rounded p-1 px-2">
              Write the answer on the first option box and tick it.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ArrowCircleLeftIcon
          onClick={() => setState({ show: true, title: "" })}
          className="h-12 w-12 mb-4 top-0 hover:bg-red-600 rounded-full bg-red-400 shadow-2xl text-white cursor-pointer absolute left-0"
        />
        {console.log(state.num)}
        <h1 className="heading mt-3">{state.title}</h1>
        Num: {state.num}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

output at console is

> test.js:57 undefined
>
> test.js:57 undefined
>
> test.js:57 undefined
>
> test.js:57 undefined

Comment: can you show the full snippet, where you are trying to console.log it

Answer (score 2):

On line 24, you have `onChange={(e) => setState({show: false, title: e.target.value})` 
this will replace your previous object with four properties with an object with just two properties. If you just want to replace show and title, you have to destructure the object first: `setState({...state, show: false, title: e.target.value })`

however, it might be easier to separate the states completely:

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(true) 
//you probably don't need the hide state, since this is just show === false (unless you use hide for something different)
const [num, setNum] = useState(1);
const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

console.log(num) //1
```

If the states change independently, this is easier to track if the states change independently. Good luck!